# Changing signs of integration limits

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

When we reverse the limits and then change the signs of the limits of the definite integral $$\int\limits_{-R}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx $$ the integral becomes
$$-\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{R}\frac{e^{-ix}}{x}dx $$

This is how the process appears to go:

(1) Changing the order of the limits of integration adds the minus sign before the integral. This is clear.

(2) Changing the signs of the limits changes the signs of the $x$'s, **but also** the sign of $dx$ appears to have changed as well, for otherwise there wouldn't be the minus sign before the integral.

Part (2) is not completely clear to me, because $dx$ arises from the Riemann sums, in which $\Delta x$ is always a positive quantity. So what exactly happens when we change the limits' signs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, there is another sign change involved. Formally, it is best to perform the substitution $u = -x$. Then $du = -dx$ and so

$$ \int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} \, dx = \int_{R}^{\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-iu}}{-u} \, (-du) = \int_{R}^{\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-iu}}{u} \, du = -\int_{\varepsilon}^{R} \frac{e^{-iu}}{u} \, du.$$

Comment: @sequence: BTW, it's not that $\Delta x$ becomes negative, it's that the integrand gets an extra minus sign which is compensated by the change of limits. Namely, if we start with $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ and perform the substitution $x = -u$ we get $\int_{-a}^{-b} -f(-u) \, du = \int_{-b}^{-a} f(-u) \, du$. For example, if $[a,b] = [0,1]$, instead of integrating $f$ on $[0,1]$ we now integrate $f(-x)$ on $[-1,0]$ and the result should be clearly the same.

Answer (score 2):

You will use

$$* \int_a^b f = -\int_b^af $$

and the substitution formula

$$** \int_a^bf (\phi (t))\phi'(t)dt=\int_{\phi (a)}^{\phi (b)}f (x)dx $$

with $\phi (t)=-t $

Thanks a lot to Stackexchange !.

Comment: $1-\int\limits_a^b f=1+\int\limits_b^a f$. Not sure why your $1$ disappears.

Comment: sorry,  Ok now ?